# Replication from Gerrit to GitLab

Tags: gerrit

I want to configure replication from Gerrit to GitLab. For "business" projects it works fine. But for "defaulted" ones (All-Projects and All-Users) it doesn't work. "Business" projects names are the same as in both Gerrit and GitLab - format "group/project".

My `replication.config` file:

```
[gerrit]
    autoReload = true
    replicateOnStartup = true
[remote "GitLab-All-Projects"]
    projects = All-Projects
    url = gitlab@gitlab.local:external-tools/gerrit-All-Projects.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    threads = 3
    mirror = true
[remote "GitLab"]
    url = gitlab@gitlab.local:${name}.git
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
    push = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    threads = 3
```

I have problem with `remote "GitLab-All-Projects"`. From `replication_log`:

```
[2021-10-22 19:57:46,038] Replication to gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Projects.git started... [CONTEXT pushOneId="7656717c" ]
[2021-10-22 19:57:46,303] Replication to gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Users.git started... [CONTEXT pushOneId="b6794909" ]
[2021-10-22 19:57:47,027] Created remote repository: gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Projects.git [CONTEXT pushOneId="7656717c" ]
[2021-10-22 19:57:47,027] Missing repository created; retry replication to gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Projects.git [CONTEXT pushOneId="7656717c" ]
[2021-10-22 19:57:47,295] Created remote repository: gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Users.git [CONTEXT pushOneId="b6794909" ]
[2021-10-22 19:57:47,296] Missing repository created; retry replication to gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Users.git [CONTEXT pushOneId="b6794909" ]
```

Of course there's no repo like `gitlab.local:All-Projects.git` in GitLab. But there is `gitlab.local:external-tools/gerrit-All-Projects.git` and user used for replication has master level privileges.

When I try to check replication status here's what I get:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 user@gerrit.local replication list --detail --json
{"Remote":"GitLab-All-Projects","Url":["gitlab@gitlab.local:external-tools/gerrit-All-Projects.git"],"Project":["All-Projects"]}
{"Remote":"GitLab","Url":["gitlab@gitlab.local:${name}.git"],"Pending":["(retry 1) [b6794909] push gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Users.git [..all..]","(retry 1) [7656717c] push gitlab@gitlab.local:All-Projects.git [..all..]"]}
```

I want to:

1. configure replication for All-Projects and All-Users within `remote "GitLab-All-Projects"`
2. exclude replication for All-Projects and All-Users within `remote "GitLab"` (to keep log clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `replication.config` as follow:

```
[gerrit]
    autoReload = true
    replicateOnStartup = true
[remote "GitLab-All-Projects"]
    projects = All-Projects
    projects = All-Users
    url = gitlab@gitlab.local:external-tools/gerrit-${name}.git
    push = +refs/*:refs/*
    threads = 3
    mirror = true
[remote "GitLab"]
    projects = ^(?:(?!All-(Users|Projects)).)*$
    url = gitlab@gitlab.local:${name}.git
    push = +refs/*:refs/*
    threads = 3
```

From the plugin [documentation](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+doc/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md#file-1): `remote.NAME.projects : Specifies which repositories should be replicated to the remote. It can be provided more than once, and supports three formats: regular expressions, wildcard matching, and single project matching. All three formats match case-sensitive.`

Bear in mind that the `All-*` projects don't necessarily contain refs under the `refs/heads` namespace, hence you will have to replicate `refs/*`. See an example below:

```
> pwd
 /tmp/gerrit/git/All-Projects.git
> git show-ref
 4c160a51808ec7ec253f125ea404c96302292940 refs/meta/config
 56a6051ca2b02b04ef92d5150c9ef600403cb1de refs/sequences/changes

> pwd
 /tmp/gerrit/git/All-Users.git
> git show-ref
 14711668d99dc83834cf2a83e6f3416bb1059321 refs/groups/5a/5a1e63b3d5542f55a25adaf390ca745b4335d995
 fdb77a3da3fbe131936161768c38f5d78deb54bd refs/groups/f7/f7ff10a4c7d8b4c3004f843fccdb2ca8decdc330
 278491ec14ecd9d856f194c0a3cc8e571a040bda refs/meta/config
 e2bc4638a57a79d63647a070a9fefcaed7628bae refs/meta/external-ids
 35a98b786adba41afb255a3b831d0bfaf62ac61f refs/meta/group-names
 44b2d5628ae9a825b22c86ed14f0ce6335ea888b refs/sequences/accounts
 e440e5c842586965a7fb77deda2eca68612b1f53 refs/sequences/groups
 c2e273e2356165687fa722fd938a0aeee3f5261e refs/users/00/1000000
```

Comment: After changing `url` value to `url = gitlab@gitlab.local:external-tools/gerrit-${name}.git` (added `${name}` placeholder) in your version it helped with unwanted log entries. But still there's no replication  `All-Projects` and `All-Users` projects to GitLab.

Comment: @MaciejSzymonowicz I have updated the config. Can you give a try with the new config? All-* don't necessarily contain refs under the `refs/heads` namespace. See the comment I have added.

Comment: Version with `push = +refs/*:refs/*` doesn't work, but `push = +refs/meta/*:refs/meta/*` works and in a log file there are entries informing about replication. But in the end in GitLab there are no changes. I suppose that it might be connected with the fact there is nothing under `refs/heads` namespace. I think I'll disable this replication for `All-*` projects. Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: @MaciejSzymonowicz no problem. Did you manually create the repository in gitlab? When a repo doesn't exist, the replication plugin creates it via an SSH command. Since the replication plugin might not have SSH access to your Gitlab server, the repository would never be created. I wonder if that's your case.

Comment: Yes, I created the repository in GitLab and gave Master level privileges to gerrit's user. Everything was done just like for other replicated repositories between Gerrit and GitLab. The other ones (with name rule `^(?:(?!All-(Users|Projects)).)*$`) are replicated without any problem.